# Google Oauth screen showing original ec2 domain. How to show the custom domain which i added?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-oauth, amazon-cloudfront

I am working on a personal MERN project which is deployed on AWS EC2, now EC2 gives a public domain itself after deployment say ex - ec2example.aws.com
Now I have added a custom domain to this ec2 instance using cloudfront and route53 say ex - customdomain.com. Everything is working fine until someone clicks on sign in with google , the oauth screen which comes, shows CHOOSE AN ACCOUNT TO CONTINUE and the main ec2 domain - ec2example.aws.com not the custom one which i added.

[image: Here is the screenshot of oauth screen]